# knative eventing with kafka is sending requests again and again

Tags: apache-kafka, knative, knative-eventing

I have successfully implemented the integration of Knative eventing within an EC2 instance, connecting it to Kafka running in Amazon Managed Streaming for Apache Kafka (MSK). The system has been configured so that when a request is sent, it triggers a corresponding event in Knative. Each incoming request should ideally result in a single corresponding response. However, I've encountered an issue where the system is generating a higher number of responses than originally anticipated. I don't know where is the issue exactly.

please help me with this and Thanks in advance.